# How can I create fake data and the data object for unit testing?

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I have a class that implements a cache and I want to write a JUnit test for it.
The class implements and interface with methods like:

```
public void insert(Object key, Object value);  
public Object getFromCache(Object key);
```

and the basic implementation is a singleton.
I am writing a JUnit test but I don't know how to properly create a dummy cache with data in order to use for testing.
Right now I am doing:

```
@Test
public void myTest() {  
    MyCache cache = MyCache.getInstance();  
    populateWithData(cache);  
    //test cache  
    asserEquals etc  
}
```

How can I avoid using the `getInstance()` and not populate on each test?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently I slightly misread your question.

As the other two answers state, if you want to have a specific cache which you can read from when running each testcase, you could use a ´@before´ method, which initializes your object to be used in your testcase. Each ´@before´ method defined is called prior to calling **each testcase**. This means that you can write the code to instantiate the object once instead of many times.

*Note* that if you want to do something different in a testcase, consider adding the customization at the top of that, instead of edition your `@before` method, since that will impact all your testcases.

Just for clarity's sake, I will include some code:

```
MyCache cache = null;

@before
public void initCache(){
    cache = MyCache.getInstance();  
    populateWithData(cache);  
}

// ... rest of your program here ...
```

**Original answer**:

You can use this if you want to do more fancy testing of more complicated objects. This can still be used in conjunction with the ´@before´ annotation

You could try [mockito](https://site.mockito.org/)...

This is basically a framework to mock off a function or class, that you are not interested in implementing in its totally, especially for testing.

Here is a sample using a mocked off list:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

// mock creation
List mockedList = mock(List.class);

// using mock object - it does not throw any "unexpected interaction" exception
mockedList.add("one");
mockedList.clear();

// selective, explicit, highly readable verification
verify(mockedList).add("one");
verify(mockedList).clear();

// you can mock concrete classes, not only interfaces
LinkedList mockedList = mock(LinkedList.class);

// stubbing appears before the actual execution
when(mockedList.get(0)).thenReturn("first");

// the following prints "first"
System.out.println(mockedList.get(0));

// the following prints "null" because get(999) was not stubbed
System.out.println(mockedList.get(999));
```

You can basically tell mockito which functions you expect to call on the object, and what you expect the result to be... very versatile. I expect that it will fulfill your needs.

Comment: I don't understand how a general answer about Mockito addresses a very specific question about fixture for cache service. Besides, according to the requirement, the OP should mock the object under test (spying) that is not necessarily the best thing to do.

Comment: I agree with your statement. re-reading the question, I do not see why my answer has been voted so high. I have edited it to reflect your comment

Answer (score 2):

'Reset' singleton before each test. More details can be found [here](http://blog.davidehringer.com/testing/test-driven-development/unit-testing-singletons/).

For example:

```
@Before
public void resetMyCacheSingleton() throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
   Field instance = MyCache.class.getDeclaredField("instance");
   instance.setAccessible(true);
   instance.set(null, null);
}
```

Comment: Does the fact that the singleton implements an interface helps to do it differently?

Comment: Classic singletons hardcode the instance valuing  into the class internal. So using or not an interface will not help you. The interface will help you if you want to mock the service implemented. But Here you don't want to mock it, you want to test it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **@BeforeClass** annotation to do something which will be common and may be computational expensive stuff.

This will ran **only once before all the testcases**.

```
@BeforeClass
public static void myTest() {  
    MyCache cache = MyCache.getInstance();  
    populateWithData(cache);  
    //test cache  
    asserEquals etc  
}
```

P.S. Since @BeforeClass can be used with static method only, populateWithData() needs to be static as well. and since populateWithData() method is static, variables used inside it must be static as well.

You can also check **@AfterClass** to clean/reset some data/resources.

Comment: But how would I get the instance of the test cache from the `@BeforeClass`?

Comment: have edited my answer to include code snippet based on example code you provided in Question.

Comment: Just to note, the JUnit 5 equivalent annotations are `@BeforeAll` and `@AfterAll` (question is tagged `junit5`).

Comment: But you marked the `@BeforeClass` to the method that would run the tests? I thought the annotation is for some other method that would initialize the data to be used by the second method

Comment: My intention was to show that the method is independent of any testcase, and it ran only once before all the test case in a particular class.